# Pad in R throwing error- Estimated returned rows, larger than 1 million in break_above

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi i am trying to bad a daily level time series data in R with the following code -

```
#daily #
daily_data <- dplyr::filter(data_yoy, date_level %in% 
                              c("DAILY", "MTD", "WTD", "L28D", "L7D", "DAY"))

daily_data_padded <- if (nrow(daily_data) > 0) {
  daily_data %>%
    pad(group = GROUP2, interval = "day")
} else {
  daily_data <- data.frame()
}

# weekly #
weekly_data <- dplyr::filter(data_yoy, date_level %in% c("WEEKLY", "WK", "WEEK")) 

weekly_data_padded <- if (nrow(weekly_data) > 0) {
  weekly_data %>%
    pad(group = GROUP2, interval = "week")
} else {
  weekly_data <- data.frame()
}

# monthly #
monthly_data <- dplyr::filter(data_yoy, date_level %in% 
                                c("MT", "MONTHLY", "MONTH")) 

monthly_data_padded <- if (nrow(monthly_data) > 0) {
  monthly_data %>%
    pad(group = GROUP2, interval = "month")
} else {
  monthly_data <- data.frame()
}

# bind #
padded_data <- bind_rows(daily_data_padded, weekly_data_padded, monthly_data_padded)
```

the code was doing its job, till the source data increased in size, and i am getting this error whenever i try to run this-

```
Estimated 2985322 returned rows, larger than 1 million in break_above
```

it looks like pad only supports 1 mill rows at once, how i can fix this error?